# Mocking an Exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I have some issues mocking a method (using mockito) which depending from the input parameter return a String or an exception.

The code of the unit test seems to be wrong but even after asking google I could not find a solution.

Thanks for any help

```
public class MyClassTest
{
    public MyClass mc;
    public ClassUnknown cu;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        mc = new MyClass();
        cu = mock(ClassUnknown.class);
        // The next two lines seems to be wrong
        when(cu.methodUnknown("hello")).thenReturn("hello there");
        when(cu.methodUnknown("???")).thenThrow(new Exception("don't know"));        
    }

    @Test
    public void testMain()
    {

        mc.mainMethod("hello");
        .....;
    }    
}
```

and here is the "classUnknown":

```
public class ClassUnknown
{
    public String methodUnknown(String s) throws Exception
    {
         // The real logic is much more complex and does some CRUD operations
        if (s.equals("Hello"))
        {
            return "Hello there";
        }
        throw new Exception("don't know");
    }
}
```

and the class to be tested:

```
public class MyClass
{

    public void mainMethod(String s)
    {
        ClassUnknown cu = new ClassUnknown();

        try
        {
            String methodUnknown = cu.methodUnknown(s);
            System.out.println(methodUnknown);
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an instance of `MyClass`. Then you're creating a mock instance of `ClassUnknown`. Then you're calling `mainMethod()` on the instance of `MyClass`. This method creates **another** instance of `ClassUnknown` and uses it. So the mock instance of `ClassUnknown` is never used anywahere and never involved in the test.

What you need to do is pass the mock instance of `ClassUnknown` to the `MyClass` instance that you're testing (or to the method that you're testing):

```
public class MyClass {

    private ClassUnknown cu;

    public MyClass(ClassUnknown cu) {
        this.cu = cu;
    }

    public void mainMethod(String s) {
        try {
            String methodUnknown = cu.methodUnknown(s);
            System.out.println(methodUnknown);
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

...

@Before
public void setUp() {
    cu = mock(ClassUnknown.class);
    // The next two lines seems to be wrong
    when(cu.methodUnknown("hello")).thenReturn("hello there");
    when(cu.methodUnknown("???")).thenThrow(new Exception("don't know"));   

    mc = new MyClass(cu); // Now, the MyClass instance will use the mock.        
}
```

This is known as dependency injection. It's crucial to have code that is testable. `MyClass` depends on `ClassUnknown`. So MyClass doens't create its own dependency. Instead, you inject the dependency (i.e. the instance of `ClassUnknown`) inside `MyClass`.

Comment: Thanks. I add to add a throws Exception to the SetUp() otherwise the IDE would mark the class for wrong but than it worked. Is it really necessary to add the throws to the SetUp() ?